# Why is cumcount faster than its .apply() equivalent?

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have this simple dataframe:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.random.randint(100000, size=50000000)})
```

Why is

```
%%time
res1 = dd.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

so much faster than:

```
%%time
res2 = dd.groupby('ID')['ID'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(len(x)), x.index))
```

?

The documentation for `cumcount` claims that these implementations are the equivalent. I presume, only in the result. `.apply()` also consumes more memory, unsurprisingly perhaps.

---

This will help me to write better code to process my pandas dataframes. So far, the only way to apply your own functions is via `.apply()` as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in pandas you use methods like `.sum()`, `.mean()`, `.cumsum()`, these operations are fully optimised (through cython/numpy).
Such methods are much faster than their lambda equivalents because with lambdas the evaluation is done in Python.

So, in general, you should try to use as many pandas methods as possible, even at the cost of having more intermediate steps in your calculations.

Here is an interesting example that could help clarify:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
test['Cond_1'] = ['A']*5 + ['B']*5
test['Cond_2'] = ['a', 'b']*5
```

When doing .sum() pandas is using C routines (very fast), where string sum is not defined, hence you just get back numerical columns.

```
test.groupby(by='Cond_1').sum()

Out[5]: 
            A         B
Cond_1                    
A       1.620708 -1.609602
B       0.146317 -1.080326
```

If you use a lambda, pandas is going to use pure python, where indeed you can sum strings!

```
test.groupby(by='Cond_1').apply(lambda x: x.sum())

Out[6]: 
             A        B     Cond_1 Cond_2
Cond_1                                  
A       1.620708 -1.609602  AAAAA  ababa
B       0.146317 -1.080326  BBBBB  babab
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be reworded instead to "why is apply so much slower?". The answer to that is because, well, `apply` was never meant to be fast.

The only difference between `apply` and a standard for loop is that, with `apply`, you can't see the loop. Yes, that means that `apply` is no better than iterating over each group sequentially, and doing whatever the function you pass to it does. `apply` is a convenience function (a plain `for` loop may sometimes be even faster), so avoid it like the plague, especially when there are faster alternatives.

`groupby.cumcount`, on the other hand, is more performant because operations on each group are vectorised to begin with.

Comment: How do I write custom functions like `groupby.cumcount`?

Comment: @SanduUrsu The answer to that is handled on a case by case basis, and requires an understanding of pandas and its features/limitations.

Comment: it’s more correct to say cumcount has a vectorized implementation (it’s not parallel in any way); nor is this particular function in cython (most are though)

Comment: In this particular case, say such a function `cumcount()` does not exist yet, how do I proceed?

Comment: @SanduUrsu Indeed, if the function does not exist, then you will need `apply`. In some other cases, however, you can settle for other vectorised alternatives.

Comment: I would add that, often, it's *worse* than a loop, especially when you are using `df.apply` on a dataframe with many columns, only some of which are used in your calculation.

Comment: @jpp I've already said that: `(a plain for loop may sometimes be even faster)`